# Generating a composite date variable

Tags: stata

I want to generate a variable `month` that has the month and year together as `2013M01`.

Below is a sample of my data:

```
clear

input expected_arrival_month year
1 2013
2 2014
3 2015
4 2016
5 2017
6 2018
end
```

I tried the following command:

```
generate month = .
replace month = 2013M01 if expected_arrival_month == 1 & year == 2013
```

However, I received the error:

```
2013M01 invalid name 
r(198)
```

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: Provide example data as code using the `dataex` command. It is not clear what your variable types are.

Answer (score 1):

For essentially all Stata purposes a numeric monthly date variable is better than anything hand- or homemade (and certainly than dates held as string variables). You can get such variables to appear as you ask. You certainly do not need to calculate individual values directly. Although this code is for a minimal dataset it will apply to all values in numeric variables as you describe. See `help datetime` for invaluable (and unavoidable) information.

```
clear
set obs 1 
generate year = 2013 
generate arrival_month = 1 

generate wanted = ym(year, arrival_month)
format wanted %tmCCYY!MNN 

list 

     +---------------------------+
     | year   arriva~h    wanted |
     |---------------------------|
  1. | 2013          1   2013M01 |
     +---------------------------+
```

(As commented, you should provide example data directly and in a way that makes variable types clear. If one or both variables are really string, apply `destring` first or use `monthly()`.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is in dealing with string rather than numeric variables.  Given that the variable you are generating is a string variable, the contents of the variable must be enclosed in quotation marks:

```
generate month = "2013M01" if expected_arrival_month == 1 & year == 2013
```

There would also be other more efficient ways to deal with this generation, for example using Stata's `egen` command (and `concat`), or `datetime` functions as indicated in another response.

Comment: I tried that and I receive the error r(109) type mismatch

Comment: It would be easier to provide a response if there were a minimum working example (as indicated by Pearly Spencer in a comment on your question), but in this case it seems likely that one of your variables `expected_arrival_month` or `year` is also a string format, and so you would also need to refer to its contents using quotation marks.

Comment: Using and concatenating strings is unlikely to be the best method here.

Comment: I agree `egen` and `concat` is not the best option.  I have edited the post to indicate that `datetime` is preferable as per Nick Cox's suggested solution.